# Creating a release using GitHub action fails with HTTP 403

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I got this workflow:

```
name: Build and Release

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*.*.*"

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.2'
          extensions: mbstring, zip

      - name: Install PHP dependencies
        run: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist

      - name: Use Node.js 16.13.0
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.0

      - name: Install required npm version
        run: npm -g install npm@8.5.5

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build assets
        run: npm run build

      - name: Create release zip
        run: zip -r release.zip .
        if: success()

      - name: Upload release.zip to GitHub Releases
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          files: release.zip
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This fails with

> ‍ Creating new GitHub release for tag v.0.5.0...
> ⚠️ GitHub release failed with status: 403
> undefined
> retrying... (2 retries remaining)

I checked https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/issues/236, what let me add the `permissions` on my workflow, but the error remains.

My question is: What am I missing? The action should be allowed to create that release?

Comment: Update your `uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0` version.

Comment: Did not solve the issue:

> ‍ Creating new GitHub release for tag v.0.5.0...
⚠️ GitHub release failed with status: 403
undefined

Comment: Do you have any tag protection rule in your repository?

Comment: This is not the case. I do not have a tag protection.

Comment: Just for testing, would a new PAT (Personal Access Token) with repo scope help? You can register it as a "New repository secret", named, e.g., GH_PAT. Then in your workflow: `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue. The error stays the same.

Comment: Try using the github cli instead of a custom action. `gh release create "v0.5.0" --title "v0.5.0" release.zip --notes ""`

Comment: is the release created on github? in which case, it might be the issue that this action is trying to create an already existing release? you might want to try an action which only adds the asset?

Comment: This issue is typically related to insufficient permissions or misconfiguration.

Comment: If there are insufficient permissions for the action, it'd be requiring an egregious excess of permissions. The workflow has the permissions required to create a release -- it has `write` for `contents` at the top level. It shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: "v.0.5.0" mind the dot after the letter "v", is it by intention or perhaps misplaced and what the error message may highlight, an error of the request as that tag does not exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the goal is to create a release automatically, it'll be much easier to just use the [gh release create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create) command rather than debug some random action.

Especially when [softprops/action-gh-release@v1](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/tree/v1) is running [this minified js](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/blob/v1/dist/index.js) where your error appears to be coming from [here](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/blob/v1/src/github.ts#L285-L310), wrapping [this version](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/blob/v1/package-lock.json#L4298-L4299) of [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@actions/github/v/5.1.1?activeTab=code), with [inadequate repository tagging](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tags) to link to an explicit version of the octokit package that that is using, to debug why the release is failing.

You can achieve the same thing with;

```yaml
    - name: Release
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: >-
        gh release create ${{ github.ref_name }}
        "release.zip#Whatever you want to call this artifact"
        --generate-notes
        --title "Version ${{ github.ref_name }} (or some other name)"
```

It's not a canonical answer with regards to [softprops/action-gh-release@v1](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/tree/v1), but it is the *GitHub-esque* way of scripting the release, using the github cli.

**Edit to add:** `permissions`

While the original question had already tried specifying permissions and still had the issue regardless of permissions, to clarify for other posters; `gh release create` requires the `contents` permission to be `write`. You can specify on either the whole workflow or just the job;

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
```

*But be aware that specifying only one permission will set the unspecified permissions to `none`, so if you're doing other things that require other permissions, you'll have to specify those also.*

Answer (score 2):

I still got the error after switching to `gh release`, but fixed this by enabling Workflow permissions / "Read and write permissions" here

`https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/settings/actions`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue using the "gh release" command, the real issue is about permissions, to fix it you have to add the permissions to your job under your job name, example:

```yaml
...
jobs:
  build:
    permissions: write-all # this is the FIX
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
...
```