# Grant GitHub permissions to create a release on when PR are closed

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, release

I am trying to automatically create a release on each PR merge.
I am using the `softprops/action-gh-release@v1` action.

For some reason each time I merge a PR the action runs, but it fails in the `Create GitHub release` (The last one) step.
The error I get is:

```
⚠️ GitHub release failed with status: 403
undefined
```

If I run the same action manually it creates the PR successfully.
If I run the action on my local fork it passes as well.

I have. a list of users permitted to execute the actions
I was thinking Maybe I should add GitHub to the list of permitted users.

1. What is the default GitHub user name (actor)?
2. May this problem caused by something else?

This is my action:

```
name: Automated Releases

env:
  CHANNEL: 'last'
  PRERELEASE: 'false'

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: write
  id-token: write

# Cancel in-progress jobs or runs for the current workflow run
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  last_release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: checkout branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main
      - name: Get Configuration
        id: configuration
        uses: rgarcia-phi/json-to-variables
        with:
          filename: './.github/workflows/config.json'
          prefix: config
      - name: Install Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - name: Set POSTFIX value
        id: set_postfix_value
        uses: ./.github/workflows/set-postfix-value
        with:
          PRERELEASE: ${{ env.PRERELEASE }}
      - name: Env Vars Configure
        id: env_vars_configure
        uses: ./.github/workflows/env-vars-configure
        with:
          CHANNEL: ${{ env.CHANNEL }}
          REF: ${{ github.ref }}
          POSTFIX: ${{ steps.set_postfix_value.outputs.postfix }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build plugin
        uses: ./.github/workflows/build-plugin
        with:
          PACKAGE_VERSION: ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
          BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH: "./.github/scripts/build-zip.sh"
      - name: Create GitHub release.    # It always fails here.
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
          target_commitish: ${{ env.CLEAN_REF }}
          files: release-*.zip
          body: "Automated release for ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}"
          prerelease: ${{ env.PRERELEASE }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The action needs access to your github token, pass it through the environment:

```
      - name: Create GitHub release.    # It always fails here.
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
          target_commitish: ${{ env.CLEAN_REF }}
          files: release-*.zip
          body: "Automated release for ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}"
          prerelease: ${{ env.PRERELEASE }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I tried that, It didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried running `gh release create` from a script step instead? That's the simplest way to create a release. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76523728/736079

Comment: You may want to try adding  `with: fetch-depth: 0` to your checkout step to make sure the full git history is available to push the tags.